# Update background color of Textboxes in Master/Slave fashion

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have three TextBoxes defined which have so to say a "master-slave" relationship. I want to achieve that the slave TextBoxes have either a red or green background color if the content matches that of the master TextBox.

Example 1:

```
TextBoxMaster.Text = "0"; Background => green (always green)
TextBoxSlave1.Text = "0"; Background => green 
TextBoxSlave2.Text = "0"; Background => green
```

Example 2:

```
TextBoxMaster.Text = "1"; Background => green (always green)
TextBoxSlave1.Text = "1"; Background => green 
TextBoxSlave2.Text = "0"; Background => red
```

I tried with Triggers but could not find a solution.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544968/how-to-create-a-wpf-validation-rule-to-ensure-two-text-fields-have-the-same-valu). It goes the same direction but I believe the information does not fit the problem. Thank you for the help!

Net 4.5.1

Comment: Bind a slave TextBox's Background to its own Text property and that of the master TextBox with a MultBinding and a multi-value converter that returns an appropriate Brush.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bool to your model which goes true if they match. 
Then you can put the default color of your slave textbox to be red and change it with a DataTrigger like this.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Matched}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</DataTrigger>
```